# Javascript add checkbox values on click

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using this JavaScript code:

```
<script>
function add(total, this_chk_bx)
{
    var thetotal = form2.thetotal.value;

    if(this_chk_bx.checked==true)
    {
        //add if its checked
        form2.thetotal.value = Number(thetotal)+Number(total);
    }
    else
    {
        //subtract if its unchecked
        form2.thetotal.value = thetotal-total;
    }
}
</script>
```

And then I have PHP/HTML code that selects from a table in a database and adds checkboxes with the values as a float field in the database.

What I'm trying to do is to make it so that when the checkboxes are ticked, it adds the values up and displays them in a text field, and then when they are unchecked, it removes that value from the field.

For some reason, when subtracting, it's displaying odd numbers and incorrectly.

I have created a fiddle here so you can also see the HMTL: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kHxmG/4/

Any ideas on what I can do to get it working properly?

Comment: Your fiddle is broken

Comment: You have an issue because of floating point values. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Comment: Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kHxmG/2/

Comment: try checking the top one, then the 2nd one, then uncheck the top one and look at the number in the total box - this is what was happening to me before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`***jsFiddle Demo***`](http://jsfiddle.net/kHxmG/5/)

I suggest you read this posts:

- [Elegant workaround for JavaScript floating point number problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1458633/1823761)
- [Is JavaScript's Floating-Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1823761)

Write a function to correct the number for you:

```
function correctNumber(number) {
    return (parseFloat(number.toPrecision(12)));
}
```

And pass your final number to this function:

```
function add(total, this_chk_bx) {
    var thetotal = (form2.thetotal.value * 1);
    var total = total * 1;

    if (this_chk_bx.checked == true) {
        //add if its checked
        form2.thetotal.value = correctNumber(thetotal + total);
    } else {
        //subtract if its unchecked
        form2.thetotal.value = correctNumber(thetotal - total);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to check the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kHxmG/5/).

Answer (score 0):

```
function add(total, this_chk_bx)
{
    var thetotal = form2.thetotal.value;
    if(this_chk_bx.checked==true)
    {
        //add if its checked
        form2.thetotal.value = ((thetotal*100)+(total*100))/100;
    }
    else
    {
        //subtract if its unchecked
        form2.thetotal.value = ((thetotal*100)-(total*100))/100;
    }
}
```

Comment: try checking the top one, then the 2nd one, then uncheck the top one and look at the number in the total box - this is what was happening to me before  - its really confusing me now lol

Comment: the link posted by @NullPointerException has the good description and solution for this issue.

Comment: ive tried doing the sprintf function like sprintf("%.2",thetotal) but still nothing - its not even displaying any values in the textfiedl

Comment: updated to use scaling method to eliminate the floating point math issue.